# How can I ignore some error in Xcode?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, xcode6

I am a new in using clang/Xcode. I have a question now that I build a code analyzer through clang-rewriter and I must get a log from return statement of every function , so I do this.

```
#define return if(fun1(),1) return
```

But when I come across this situation , the clang cannot make me compile success
[image: The situation that I cannot solve]

As I have to build the prj automatically , I want to find a way to ignore this error, like g++ ,I can through '-Wno-return-type' to ignore this warning, but I configure this in Xcode,it is not used.  :(sad

Answer (score 0):

IMO the problem is not the warning but the way you `return` from the block. Instead of adding an explicit `else` branch you can just write the following (which is semantically the same):

```
if(cmp != NSOrderedSame) {

    return cmp;
}

return [lhs.tagName compare:rhs.tagName];
```

Comment: But I cannot change the source code of the prj. I just develop an tool and config the Xcode

Comment: That is unfortunate. In this case the only thing you can try is to add `-Wno-return-type` to `Other Warning Flags` in your target's build settings in Xcode.